# creating list of top values in all columns pandas

Tags: pandas, list, selection

I am trying to get list of top 2 value counts in all columns in my pandas dataframe. DF is something like this

```
            column1          column2          column3
 1           apple            red               cat
 2          banana            blue              dog
 3          grapes            yellow            cat
 4           apple            blue              cat
 5          banana            red               tiger
 6          banana            blue              dog
```

I want the result to be in the form of a list. Something like this:

```
 ['banana', 'apple', 'blue', 'red', 'cat', 'dog']
```

can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) per all columns and filter top values by index with slice (because `value_counts` sorting values) and then convert values to list:

```
a = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()[:2].index.tolist()).to_numpy().ravel('F').tolist()
print (a)
['banana', 'apple', 'blue', 'red', 'cat', 'dog']
```

List comprehension solution with flatten values:

```
a = [x for c in df.columns for x in df[c].value_counts()[:2].index]
print (a)
['banana', 'apple', 'blue', 'red', 'cat', 'dog']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension calling [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) combined with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

out = list(chain.from_iterable(df[c].value_counts()[:2].index for c in df))
```

output: `['banana', 'apple', 'blue', 'red', 'cat', 'dog']`